# how can i take screenshot of firefox with addon result

Tags: linux, firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, screenshot

Myself on kali linux with firefox and calomel ssl validation addon,i have many addons installed at my firefox,

Main problem which i face while taking screenshot was i cant take the screenshot with firefox,

Sample output which i need was like below[taken from addon firefox] :

[image]

Whenever i press <kbd>printscr</kbd> or using the default screen grabber the addon result get disappeared ,is it there any way to capture screenshot of firefox with addon result?

Comment: If you have a screen grabber that supports delayed capture, you can probably set a delay of a few seconds, and open the plugin window before the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to use an application that simply takes screenshots in time intervals.  This way no keys are touched.  Something like [AtuScreenCap.](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/free-software-downloads/capture-screenshots-at-defined-time-intervals-automatically/)

I haven't tried it myself however if I had this situation, this is what I would do.  Set this up before you want your screenshot, set the time and where to save the images, then go and do your stuff.

Hope this helps.